Can I (EU citizen) visit the West Bank in mid-2024?
Acknowledging the obvious dangers, is it possible currently to get to the West Bank as an average person?
If so, would it be advisible to enter from Israel or from Jordan?

Better to ask your foreign affair offices. Not just because "I can/I cannot enter", but eventually your country may put warning and restrictions, which may cancel travel insurances or help from your country. In addition you may get information on where to get help (in case of changes, and they may get in contact with you for evacuations. In any case, I do not think "West Bank" in general has restrictions

Yes, you can.
You cannot enter through Jordan directly into the Palestinian territory though, either way you'll have to go through the Israeli border checks first. TLV airport will probably be more convenient.
The West Bank is comparatively safe, but I would strongly advise against trying to enter Gaza.

The West Bank is also comparatively unsafe. It just depends what you compare it to. I suspect that if organised tours are still running (from Jerusalem), and you're on a tour, you can expect to be totally fine.

Well yes, I was comparing to Gaza, since the question was tagged "Palestine".

Just for clarification: there's no way of entering the West Bank without passing through Israeli checkpoints. The entire border with Jordan and much of the West Bank territory is controlled by Israel, only certain pockets of land are administered by the Palestinian Authority. But these are completely surrounded by areas administered by Israel, so there's no way of entering the Palestinian areas without passing through Israel first.
Unless you found super cheap tickets to Amman (unlikely!), it's better to fly to Tel Aviv and proceed from there. This way you'll avoid the cumbersome Jordan-to-Israel border crossing.
Regarding safety and security, the areas under Palestinian Authority are not all equal. Bethlehem and Jericho are the safest, and visited by many tourists. Hebron, Nablus and Ramallah are also reasonably safe. Besides these, there's not much to see in the West Bank either. In any case, you should not be looking obviously Jewish or display anything related to the state of Israel, that's a very bad idea. The goal is to look like an average western tourist.
Oh yes, and forget about the Gaza Strip.

Currently, the best way to see Gaza is by satellite.

Satelite view in online mapsites is never current, mostly it is a few years behind.
